Bamboo's JUnit Parser won't parse my test results and failing to find the results in file path
6
Hello Team,
I was trying to add some automated test cases to my project with Bamboo and have been facing some problems. We actually designed the CI/CD pipeline to run the automated test cases. These test cases are executing correctly, and it is successfully generating the output.xml file at this path: C:\Users\shafi\bamboo-agent-home\xml-data\build-dir\ESMP-QAAUT-IEJ\log\20240807_15938\output.xml.
After this, I added the JUnit Parser Plugin in a Bamboo task and provided this path \ESMP-QAAUT-IEJ***.xml to parse the result under "Specify custom results directories." I have tried many ways to fix the issue, but it remains unresolved. Please observe the issue below and provide me with suggestions.
I'm getting the following error when executing Bamboo's JUnit Parser:
Parsing test results under C:\Users\shafi\bamboo-agent-home\xml-data\build-dir\ESMP-QAAUT-IEJ...
Failing task since test cases were expected but none were found.
Finished task 'JUnit Parser Task' with result: Failed
